# Apache POI Difference between SXSSFSheet.addMergedRegion() & SXSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe()?

Tags: apache-poi, sxssf

I am using Apache POI to build excel file. Since the data might be very large I decided to use SXSSFWorkbook instead of XSSFWorkbook. In application runtime I can see that SXSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe() run faster than SXSSFSheet.addMergedRegion() but I can't find any docs related to it. So I wonder is there any risk of using SXSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SXSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe` simply calls [XSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#addMergedRegionUnsafe-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress-). See [source code of SXSSFSheet](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_0/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l382):

```
...    
@Override
public int addMergedRegionUnsafe(CellRangeAddress region) {
 return _sh.addMergedRegionUnsafe(region);
}
...
```

There `_sh` is `XSSFSheet`.

And in `XSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe` the behavior is documented:

> Adds a merged region of cells (hence those cells form one). Skips
> validation. It is possible to create overlapping merged regions or
> create a merged region that intersects a multi-cell array formula with
> this formula, which may result in a corrupt workbook. To check for
> merged regions overlapping array formulas or other merged regions
> after `addMergedRegionUnsafe` has been called, call
> `validateMergedRegions()`, which runs in O(n^2) time.

So `addMergedRegionUnsafe` runs faster because it skips validation. So using this your program needs considering not to create overlapping merged regions and not to create a merged region that intersects a multi-cell array formula with this formula. Else the result workbook gets corrupted.

Source for [XSSFSheet.addMergedRegionUnsafe](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_0/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l307) for completeness.